# Connecting Android to Arduino with Processing

Tags: android, processing, ethernet, arduino-uno

I am working on a project that visualizes data from a Motion Sensor and a photoresistor. For the visualization I use Processing to read from the serial port and as such from the Arduino and then use the values to visualize or draw a flower which changes colors based on the state of the sensors.
I want to take it a step further and use an android device as a display to show off my visualisation. What can my options be considering the fact that I want to avoid adding on a bluetooth shield for the Arduino and that I already have an ethernet shield for Arduino Uno btw. I am also open to visualizing it on a webpage and using the Android device to access the network. How then do I make the communication between the Arduino and Processing

Answer (score 1):

Considering you already have an ethernet shield, I'd say you plug in the ethernet cable in your Arduino and in the router. Then you use the Ethernet library from Arduino to display the data on a webpage. Then you can either go for making your webpage fancy, or just store plain data there which you access with your android app using http-requests and use that data to display them in your app.

I've done this myself (with an Arduino Nano, an ENC28j60 Ethernet module, and the EtherCard library). What I did was give the Arduino a local IP address (no DHCP involved), so I'm sure the Arduino is always reachable at the same IP. I'm sure there is a way to make your Arduino accessible from outside (external), may you want that, but I haven't looked into that yet.

Maybe have a look at these tutorials/examples:

 http://tronixstuff.com/2013/12/06/arduino-tutorials-chapter-16-ethernet/ 

 http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Ethernet-Shield-Tutorial/step1

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I guess with your suggestion I would have to take the Processing out, But I am not sure if its possible to represent the data as the flower I want....But I will look into it. Thanks for your feedack and I will look into the Tutorials.....Thanks again!

Comment: @nana-k You're welcome! What do you mean with a flower? A webpage or Android can do a lot to visualise things, just Google for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay Abby. I want to visualize the states of my sensors with colors. I will just google

Comment: Did you succeed or get any closer yet?